# Update status to approved via AJAX when clicking a button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I update a 'status' field as approved when I click on a button?

```
function UpdateRecord(id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update.php",
    data: 'id=' + id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Record successfully updated");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! unfortunately there is not enough information to answer your question. What is the db structure, what makes an item "approved", ...? What have you tried and where did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
  function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "update.php",
     data: {id:id},
     cache: false,
     success: function(response)
     {
       alert("Record successfully updated");
     }
 });
   }
 </script>
```

and in update.php

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['id']))
   { 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
   // update here to this id..
   }
   ?>
```